# Building qt creator from scratch: after mingw32-make clean step, *.pluginspec are removed

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator, qmake

I have compiled QT 2.3.1 from source. Here is the process:

```
cd c:\qtcreator
qmake c:\qtcreatorsrc\qtcreator.pro -o c:\qtcreater\Makefile -spec win32-g++ -r CONFIG+=release
mingw32-make release
```

After this, the qtcreator was compiled succesful and I was able to run it. Then I decided to clean all object files that are not needed anymore and I have done:

```
mingw32-make clean
```

After this, I was not able to start qt. The message I get is: "Failed to load core: Could not find 'Core.pluginspec' in C:\QtCreator\lib\qtcreator\plugins,C:\QtCreator\plugins"

**After short investigation I have noticed that clean step has really removed all *.pluginspec files from lib\qtcreator\plugins. Is this bug in generation of makefile? Have I done something wrong?**

*I could skip clean step, but I see no point in keeping all object files since they occupy more then 1GB of disk space.*